# To stop reloading web page In Asp.net on any button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

how stop postback on any button click. My page is reloading as soon as i click on reset button on the registration page, i want to reset the form without reloading the page itself.

Comment: Why don't you try javascript to do it?

Comment: actually, its not only the functioning of reset button, reloading of the page occur on evry click when i am establishing panel to visible.

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities:

- Simply set the attribute `AutoPostBack="false"` on your button or whatever control.
- As an alternative you could also add the following javascript to the click event of the button :

  ```
  onclick="return false"
  ```

  This prevents the button from submitting.

Comment: If `AutoPostBack` is set to `false`, OP will need to write some javascript to rest the registration page.

Comment: but i do have onclick event olready on  button, i tried the same onclick="return false" & onclicentclick ,but its not working.

Comment: Well it depends how the postback is registred on the button.  If it gets registered by javascript then `return false` wont work

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
<asp:button runat="server".... OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to know about Sever Control and normal HTML control.
If you used Server Button Control  then your Page reload on each click.
If you wan to stop it then you have to use AutoPostBack="false", using this your server side method calling is stop.
Otherwise use Normal HTML Button Control and use JavaScript to reset your form.

Comment: i have an issue regarding panel visiblity which is on onclick event of a link button on the same page. when clicking on the link to show up the hidden panel but page gets reload, i tried onclick="return false" and same with onclientclick but dint get the result i xpcted. can u pls validate this?

Comment: Have you know about Ajax in Aps.net..?You can try Ajax Update panel, which help you to reload page partially. In Update panel, only part of the page will reload  [link][1] [1]:msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx